# How do you set the namespace of a Groovy Node object to another value?

Tags: xml, groovy, namespaces

I'm converting an XML document from one namespace (and schema) to another. JDOM allows us to call Element.setNamespace() (which also takes care of the attributes for the element). The closest I can see with a Groovy Node is

```
myNode.name = new QName("http://my/new/namespace", myNode.name.localPart)
```

But I'm not confident that this is the best way - in particular, it doesn't take care of the attributes. Is this even possible with Node? And if so, what's the idiomatic way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way off-hand...  You could just use JDOM though (converted to a Groovy script [from this example](http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/XML/programming/jdomexample.html))

```
@Grab(group='org.jdom', module='jdom', version='1.1')
import org.jdom.*
import org.jdom.input.*
import org.jdom.output.*

new SAXBuilder().build( new URL( 'http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/XML/xml/recipes.xml' ) ).with { document ->
  def newDoc = new Element( 'collection' ).with { element ->
    addContent document.rootElement.getChild( 'recipe', Namespace.getNamespace( 'http://recipes.org' ) ).detach()
    new Document( element )
  }
  new XMLOutputter().output( newDoc, System.out )
}
```